# Detect value in an array coming from Socket.IO

Tags: javascript, socket.io

I send an array to SOCKET.IO server from a webpage client

```
var trads = 4000+','+7000+','+6000+','+2000+','+4398+','+6094;
var temp = new Array();
temp = trads.split(',');

socket.emit("assign", temp);
```

My SOCKET.IO server receives array and emits to other webpage **client.php**:

```
socket.on("assign", function(data){
    var temp = data;
    socket.broadcast.emit("check", temp);
});
```

And in **client.php** (that has an input value in array) I want to display a message in console :

```
<html>
<body>
<input type="text" id="num" value="4000">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.0.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/socket.io/2.0.3/socket.io.js">
</script>

<script>

 var socket = io.connect(URL_SERVER);

 socket.on("check",function(data){
   var temp = data;
   var idtr = $("#num").val();

  console.log(temp);

  if(idtr in temp){
    console.log("It has value");
  } else {
    console.log("It has no value");
  }
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

But It's still displaying "It has no value" message. How can I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [indexOf()](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Objets_globaux/Array/indexOf)

```
  if(temp.indexOf(idtr) > -1){
    console.log("It has value");
  } else {
    console.log("It has no value");
  }
```

indexOf return index. So you can use it to access your value by the way.

**Edit :** I missed the `-1` condition. **indexOf** `return -1` if nothing is found

Comment: I tried your solution but in client pages where doesn't have value in array display "It has value" and viceversa.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution validating according to indexOf() result.

```
var index = temp.indexOf(idtr);

if(index>=0){
    console.log("It has value");
} else {
    console.log("It has no value");
}
```

Comment: You shall put `> -1` in your conditions.